# Problem with ArcCurvature

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

When comparing the outputs of

```
Table[ArcCurvature[Log[x], x] /. x -> k, {k, 1, 2, 1/2}]
Table[ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x] /. x -> k  , {k, 1, 2, 1/2}] // FullSimplify

Table[ArcCurvature[Log[x], x] /. x -> k, {k, 1, 2, .5}]
Table[ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x] /. x -> k  , {k, 1, 2, .5}] // FullSimplify
```

I get proper results in the first three cases. Further I noticed that in the case of `2 Log[x]` I have to add `FullSimplify` (Why?) But what happens in the fourth line? Why do I get the following output:

```
 {0.0894427 Sqrt[29. + Derivative[1][Abs][1.] (-50. + 25. Derivative[1][Abs][1.])], ....}
```

What do I do wrong? How do I get proper results? I run M 12.2.0.0

Comment: You probably ran afoul of the general principle in Mathematica whereby complex values are assumed by default. You might want `Assuming[x > 0, ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x]] /. x -> Range[1, 5, 1/2]`.

Comment: Yes! Good Idea! You made my day! Works for 0.5 too! But to me still a mystery why it works in line three but not in line four.

Comment: Since you didn't invoke `Abs` explicitly and since I would expect `ArcCurvature` to be a function over the reals, this seems a bug to me.  You should report it to WRI. Maybe they want `ArcCurvature` extended to the `Complexes`, but the docs should point out what to do in a case like yours, if so.

Comment: Yes, I will do. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document, `Abs` is not a differentiable function.We can use the two approachs to avoid this.

```
abs = Sqrt[#^2] &;
ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x] /. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify
ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x] /. Abs -> abs
```

```
Table[ArcCurvature[2 Log[x], x] /. x -> k, {k, 1, 2, .5}] /. 
 Abs -> RealAbs
```

Comment: Very cunning! Good idea!